# What applications/IDEs are out there to manage NoSQL database systems?

Tags: database, ide, nosql

NoSQL are an alternative to RDBMS, that work well with simple data models holding vast volumes of data. MongoDB, Google's BigTable, Dojo's Persevere, Amazon's Dynamo, Facebook's Cassandra are some examples.  Could you state your favorite application/IDE that can manage (i.e. insert or query data) such databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoSQL database are at their childhood, there are no real managing applications i am aware of, but most nosql database provide some form of an cli-tool to interact with the database.
Developing such managing applications is also non trivial, in SQL based systems with indexes you can show efficient a listing of rows beginning with the first and ending with the n-th row of a table containing m rows (n < m)
But NoSQL database are mainly Key-Value-Stores with a hashtable-lookup, so you can't really look efficient at the first n data sets.

Sure there's are exceptions like Redis and MongoDB which provide some form of sorted sets and indexes, but they are really the exception.
If you need such a tool write a minimalistic version like [Try Redis](http://try.redis-db.com/)
 or [MongoDB Browser Shell](http://www.mongodb.org/#), will not be much effort and provides everything you can do to query your database.

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB you can use RoboMongo, MonguVUE etc.  CouchDB has it's own interface but there are plenty of GUI's available but also depending on the type of NoSQL you will use as there are four categories.